# .net Core & Swashbuckle/Swagger: How to provide raw json example?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, webapi

I have a WebAPI controller with an operation returning a JSON schema. This JSON return value cannot be created by serializiation, so I designed the operation method as follow:

```
    [HttpGet("{serviceName}/contract")]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(object))]
    public IActionResult GetContract(string serviceName)
    {
        return Content("{ \"type\": \"object\" }", "application/json"); // for example ...
    }
```

Now I like to have a or some documented return values for Swagger. But I'm unable to do that. There is the `SwaggerRequestExample` attribute, but as said before, this requires a return type which in my case is not applicable.

Basically I search for a way of something like that (just dynamic):

```
[SwaggerResponseExample((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, "{\"anyJson\": \"Yes, I am!\"}")]
```

Or of course, even better like that:

```
[SwaggerResponseExample((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, RawJsonFabricType="TypeName", RawJsonStaticMethod="MethodName")]
```

Use case: The JSON schemas I need to return in operation method are stored in a database and are not created within the program code itself.

A concrete example of such a JSON schema value is:

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Help will be very appreciated.
Thanks!

I'm using c#.net core 6.

Comment: It could be easily created using a C# POCO object.

Comment: Since my JSON is dynamic, I don't have any type reflecting the JSON string, so POCO is no-go

Comment: In order to be able to answer this question we need specific details of your case. Its not why why you need it, give a good example.

Comment: @JHBonarius: See added use case ...

Comment: I mean a _concrete_ example, or preferably even multiple examples. Don't just give an abstract description. I mean: I still not know your data source. I will warn in advance: C# is not a dynamically types language. You will likely need something (a library or self-written) that converts your JSON schema to a dynamic type (`ExpandoObject` or sorts)

Comment: @JHBonarius: Example of JSON added. I agree with you, extracting the JSON from a type is probably not possible, that's why I search a possibility to define 'raw-json' ...

Comment: how can you document a schema which has no schema

Comment: @MarkHomer: Is that not just, what I asked for? :) Since the output can be variable, I like to build variable examples ...

Comment: Might wanna look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afer trying arround I came to the solution:

First: Add `ExampleProvider` and use generic type `JsonDocument` (from `System.Text.Json`):

```
    public class ServiceDemandContractExampleProvider : IExamplesProvider<JsonDocument>
    {
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public JsonDocument GetExamples()
        {
            var jsonToShow = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{
  ""$id"": ""https://example.com/person.schema.json"",
  ""$schema"": ""https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"",
  ""title"": ""Person"",
  ""type"": ""object"",
  ""properties"": {
                ""firstName"": {
                    ""type"": ""string"",
      ""description"": ""The person's first name.""
                },
    ""lastName"": {
                    ""type"": ""string"",
      ""description"": ""The person's last name.""
    },
    ""age"": {
                    ""description"": ""Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero."",
      ""type"": ""integer"",
      ""minimum"": 0
    }
            }
        }");

            return jsonToShow;
        }
    }
```

To `JsonDocument.Parse` put whatever JSON (in my case loaded content from database).

Then add the follow attributes to the operation method:

```
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(object))]
[SwaggerResponseExample((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(ServiceDemandContractExampleProvider))]
```

And it works:
[image]